# Допустимо ли использовать незарегистрированную версию Sublime Text в организации?

Tags: sublime-text, лицензирование

Подскажите, можно ли использовать Sublime Text 3 без лицензионного ключа в организации? Допустимо ли это в соответствии с их политикой, и не нарушает ли это российские законы?

Comment: Скорее всего - нет. Sublime Text можно бесплатно попробовать. На сайте есть специальная **Business License**.

Comment: Недопустимо, предоставляется **бесплатно только ознакомительная версия** как для предприятия, так и для частного использования.

Comment: @AlexKrass, период ознакомления же никак не ограничивается, получается, что можно ознакамливаться сколько угодно?

Comment: @MaximZasorin, ознакамливаться можно сколько угодно, но это настолько ограниченное толкование, что у проверяющих могут возникнуть вопросы. К примеру в толкование "evaluated for free" явно не входит написание на нем рабочих проектов.

Comment: @AlexKrass, да, согласен, наверное так оно и есть. А подскажите, еще, если вы в теме, на какие программы распространяется законодательство, на любые какие только можно найти в интернете? Или производитель ПО должен быть как-то представлен в России?

Comment: @MaximZasorin у каждой программы есть автор(ы), согласно закону авторские права принадлежат ему и охраняются законом. Проще говоря закон действует на любые программы, ничего не требуется и использовать эти программы можно только с его согласия. Обычно таким согласием выступает лицензия, описывающая все нюансы использования. Многие предоставляют бесплатные лицензии, где опять же все это прописано и опубликовано. С организаций требуют строгие доказательства правомерности использования как правило. Еще иногда приходится доказывать свое авторство, но это уже другая история.

Comment: @AlexKrass большое спасибо за ответ.